# Case insenstive groupBy in lodash

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I'm doing groupBy on location key. However, lodash is treating the values differently. How do we tell Lodash to do an case insensitive grouping? In my example above, Chicago and chicago should be treated the same. Thanks!

```
[
    { 
        tournament : 'basketball',
        location : 'chicago'
    },
    { 
        tournament : 'baseball', 
        location : 'Chicago' 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the location to lowercase in the iterator function:

```
    var result = _.groupBy(list, function(value){
        return value.location.toLowerCase();
    });
```